# Local storage keeps resetting after reload

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, local-storage

I'm trying to use local storage to store and array it works but when I reload it resets the array. I have looked through some similar questions and did everything I could understand from the answers provided so I guessed the problem might be from my code so please help me review it. Thanks in advance

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Modal from './Modal'


function Boards() {
    const [boards, setboards] = useState(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('boards')) || []);
    const [title, settitle] = useState('');
    localStorage.setItem('boards', JSON.stringify(boards));


    const handleChange = (e) => {
        settitle(e.target.value)
    }
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        if (title.length === 0) {
            return;
        }
        setboards(prev => (
            [
                ...prev,
                title
            ]
        ))
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <ul id="boards">
                <BoardList boards={boards} />
            </ul>
            <Modal title={title} handleChange={handleChange} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
        </div>
    )
}
function BoardList({ boards }) {
    const history = useHistory()
    return (
        <>
            {
                boards.map((board, index) => (
                    <li key={index} onClick={() => { history.push('./workspace') }}>
                        <h3>{board}</h3>
                    </li>
                ))}

        </>
    )
}
export default Boards
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set your initial boards state to the boards in localStorage

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Modal from './Modal'


function Boards() {
    const [boards, setboards] = useState( JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('boards') || []);
    const [title, settitle] = useState('');
    localStorage.setItem('boards', JSON.stringify(boards));


    const handleChange = (e) => {
        settitle(e.target.value)
    }
    const handleSubmit = () => {
        if (title.length === 0) {
            return;
        }
        setboards(prev => (
            [
                ...prev,
                title
            ]
        ))
        localStorage.setItem('boards', JSON.stringify(boards));


    }
    return (
        <div>
            <ul id="boards">
                <BoardList boards={boards} />
            </ul>
            <Modal title={title} handleChange={handleChange} handleSubmit={handleSubmit} />
        </div>
    )
}
function BoardList({ boards }) {
    const history = useHistory()
    return (
        <>
            {
                boards.map((board, index) => (
                    <li key={index} onClick={() => { history.push('./workspace') }}>
                        <h3>{board}</h3>
                    </li>
                ))}

        </>
    )
}
export default Boards
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. It worked but i don't really understand what I did, please can you shed some light on it. I'm really sorry for any inconveniences.

Comment: basically what's going on is the state for boards is being set to the localstorage item boards if it exists.  if it does not exist it is set to an empty array.  that way if a user refreshes the page, we know that the local storage item boards exists in local storage and will be the initial state of boards.

Comment: hopefully that made a bit more sense

Comment: Okay, I understand a bit. Thanks once again, I've been on it for hours now. I'm really grateful Thank you

Comment: yeah for sure! if this answer worked for you could you give me a checkmark if possible

Comment: Hi, I'm back again, I'm having a bit of an issue same code no changes but now I'm getting a new error : board.map is not a function . it's like it doesnt take board to be a array

Comment: Hi before mapping do this boards && boards.map i will update answer as well

Comment: also change the useState of boards to this: const [boards, setboards] = useState( JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('boards') || null)

Comment: I think it's trying to map before the localStorage loads

Comment: is the boards data an array? console log boards

Comment: then the changes I suggested should do the trick to ensure that mapping only occurs once boards has loaded.  is the item you are storing in localstorage an array?

Comment: please can you explain the boards && boards.map

Comment: initially boards is null which is falsy, so it waits for boards to become an array which is truthy to begin mapping

Comment: yes, it is an array. I was planning on making it a array of objects as i proceed, just trying to understand the main logic. its an array

Comment: it's giving a new error of object is null not iterable

Comment: I made some corrections, your first correct was right just that you were missing a closing bracket. Thats the reason it was giving me the error. Thank you very much